# How to generate a unique id for different visitors with PHP?

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

The value will be used as:

```
from INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

which defines different visitors that haven't login.

How to properly generate that number with PHP?

**EDIT**:

If using database as follows:

```
create table user_visits(
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    primary key(id)
);
```

How to insert a new record into it?

Comment: 365 questions, only 7 upvotes and 91 selected answers. Lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id:

```
INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: That's from database.How to do that from PHP?

Comment: You posted the database field to insert to, so I thought you want to store them in the database. INSERT and select the inserted id with mysql_insert_id().

Comment: OK,I've declined to use database now.But how to insert a new record into it?

Comment: `INSERT INTO user_visits (id) VALUES (NULL);`

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a value in a database each time with an auto_increment column.

You can also use the php function uniqid().